# How to import data from txt file to sql in a table format for analysis?

Tags: java, python, r, database, excel

I am evaluating a biometrics SDK, and I have the results i.e. match scores in a txt file in the following format, where row and col represent subject ID's. Some of the subjects have multiple image samples as shown in example.

(row # , col # , MatchScore)

> Ex: 3, 4, 84

I need to organize the data in the following format:

```
        sub1 sub2 sub3 .. ..
sub1    100   56   36    
sub2    74    97   17     
sub3    39    59   91    
..
..
```

So that I can do some analysis on the data and plot the ROC and CMC curves from that data. The text file is over 4GB as there are more than 15000 subjects for which I am evaluating the SDK. Please advice, what is the best way to import this data into a well structured form and analyze.

Comment: Every enterprise level database will have a bulk load feature (such as bcp or db2 load).  You might want to look for the one that is relevant for your database.

Comment: can you elaborate on the transformation/reorganization you need done after the initial comma-separated data is read in? It's not clear to me from your question

Comment: I have about 15000 subjects in the gallery and I have used multi-threading approach to generate the match scores. So I have about 225,000,000 comparisons done and stored in a random order in the txt file. I need to organize them so as to plot a confusion matrix based on a determined threshold value. And finally plot ROC and CMC curves to evaluate the classifier (i.e. SDK).